# How to alignment right to left in JFrame/java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, alignment, vertical-alignment

I wrote this code, but I'm having a problem with making it align from right to left.
I tried several things, but none of them works.
I know it can be done by playing with the coordinates, but I want a way that I wouldn't need to do that for every word. How am I supposed to do it the right way?

code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class GUI {
//messages 
public static final String ConnectC_MSG    = "התחבר"    ;
public static final String DisconnectC_MSG = "התנתק"    ;
public static final String ServerLBL_MSG   = "שרת יעד:"  ;
public static final String UsernameLBL_MSG = ":שם משתמש";
public static final String PasswordLBL_MSG = ":סיסמא"   ;
public static final String PortLBL_MSG     = ":פתחה"    ;
//sizes
public static final int SreverTxtfield_Width   = 10;
public static final int UsernameTxtfield_width = 10;
public static final int PasswordTxtfield_width = 10;
public static final int PortTxtfield_width     = 5 ;
public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH  = 800;
public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;


static JFrame frame1;
static Container pane;

static JButton btnConnect = new JButton(ConnectC_MSG),
               btiDiscinnect = new JButton(DisconnectC_MSG);
static JLabel lblServer   = new JLabel(ServerLBL_MSG),
              lblUsername = new JLabel(UsernameLBL_MSG),
              lblPassword = new JLabel(PasswordLBL_MSG),
              lblPort     = new JLabel(PortLBL_MSG);

static JTextField txtServer   = new JTextField(SreverTxtfield_Width),
                  txtUsername = new JTextField(UsernameTxtfield_width),
                  txtPort     = new JTextField(PortTxtfield_width);

static JPasswordField txtPassword = new JPasswordField(PasswordTxtfield_width);

static Insets insets;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame1 = new JFrame ("הדגמה");
    frame1.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    frame1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    pane = frame1.getContentPane();
    pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

    insets = pane.getInsets();
    pane.setLayout(null);   
    pane.add(lblServer);
    pane.add(lblUsername);
    pane.add(lblPassword);
    pane.add(lblPort);
    pane.add(txtServer);
    pane.add(txtUsername);
    pane.add(txtPassword);
    pane.add(txtPort);
    lblServer.setBounds((int)(insets.right),insets.top,
            lblServer.getPreferredSize().width, lblServer.getPreferredSize().height);
    txtServer.setBounds(lblServer.getX()+lblServer.getWidth(), lblServer.getY()+lblServer.getHeight(),
            txtServer.getPreferredSize().width, txtServer.getPreferredSize().height);

    frame1.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Comment: You are adding multiple components in `frame1.getContentPane()`. That is wring. Use `JPanel` and add all the component in it. and finall add `JPanel` in frame's content pane.

Comment: i'm new to this... how the new code needs to be like?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: Should I share you the complete code? Have you tried what I have suggested?

Comment: and the how am i suppose to align it to the right?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );
panel.add(...);
panel.add(...);
...
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

and the components will align to the ride side of the frame.

Also, get rid of all the static variables. That is NOT the way to write a class.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Flow Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) for more information and examples. If will show you a better way to structure your class without all the static stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  pane = new JPanel();
```

in place of

```
 pane = frame1.getContentPane();
```

and remove this line

```
pane.setLayout(null);
```

and finally add `pane` to `JFrame`

```
 frame1.getContentPane().add(pane);
```

Comment: That is terrible code for reasons I have already mentioned in my answer. Just because the OP post poorly structured code does not mean you should do the same. That is why I provided the link to the Swing tutorial which does it properly and so the OP can also learn to do it properly.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you. You have to learn first. Try what @camickr has suggested.

Comment: Use `pane = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT) );` as suggested by @camickr.

Comment: why can't i use contentpane like this guy used ? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/23017-basic-gui-tutorial-in-java/

Comment: @user3504367, why can't you read the Swing tutorial and learn how to write the code better? I've already told you that code example is terrible because of all the static variables. Now that I see it also uses a null layout the code example is event worse.